# Convergence on sum of cos

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, trigonometric-series

> How to find the range of x on this sum to converge?
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^∞{{\cos nx}\over{n}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Using [the Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_test) with $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n=\cos(nx),\ x\ne0$ we see that the series is convergent for $x\ne0$. It's clearly not convergent for $x=0$.